# Update list item with HTML Form,JS,etc...?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, updatelistitems

I got asked to solve the below problem. On our Sharepoint 2013 Teamsite there is a list with teammembers. {Name;IsAvailable;Person}

- Name = Textfield
- IsAvailable = True/False combobox
- Person = Person or Group field

What needs to be accomplished?

An easy way so a Teammember can change his availability.
We are not allowed to use SP-Designer,Infopath, VS Studio!

My Ideal solution would be a simple toggle button on the homepage. Any ideas if this is possible. Any other suggestions? The goal is to make this task for the team as easy as possible. (As less clicks as possible)

Thanks for your input.

Comment: How comfy are you with adding JavaScript? Basically its: Display Button, Update Item with JSOM/REST code. You can use Client Side Rendering [Cisar plugin on Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en) to develop without the need for any tools

Comment: Hi, I am new to JavaScript so I small example would be very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle button on home page and update the list using REST API.
Populating, Adding and Updating of data can be done using Rest API.
Reference for the same : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

You can also use JSOM/SP Service as suggested by Danny.

Also you can add list view web part on home page with filter of Person=[ME].
So user can update availability status from the view.